# How to make antlr4 parses part of the correct syntax instead of throwing an error node?

Tags: antlr4

I used a *parser.g4* to parse a sql-like language.

```sql
1. SELECT a FROM b WHERE
2. SELECT a FROM b WHERE c
3. SELECT a FROM b HAVING
```

[image: WHERE] [image: HAVING]
In 1,2 "WHERE" was recognized as Error Node, 
In 3 "HAVING" was recognized as part of select_statement and hint missing search_condition.
I found that select_statement's parent statement has two "WHERE search_conditon" clause.Then I tried,proved that HAVING/ORERD BY were recognized like syntax3 while option_clause and WHERE were recognized like example 1 and 2. How can I make they all be parsed like example3?

**parser.g4 main department is as follow:**

```
dml_clause
    : delete_statement
    | select_statement
    ;
delete_statement
    : DELETE FROM table_sources
      (WHERE search_condition)?
      option_clause? ';'?
    ;
select_statement
    : SELECT 
      select_list
      (FROM table_sources)?
      (WHERE search_condition)?
      (HAVING having=search_condition)?
      order_by_clause?
      option_clause? 
    ;
```

Comment: I have not fully understood what you want but it sounds like you don't get errors in cases 1 and 2 and want to have them. Is that correct?

Comment: I want parser recognized 1，2  as a select_statement(so I can deal with tokens after "WHERE" in visitor).Now example 1 is divided into two parts, "SELECT a FROM b"(a legal select_statement) and "WHERE" (an error node)".  Example 3 is just one select_statement.

Comment: I add two visualized parsed tree photos in actual project, whose parser has many layers,but action is same as parser.g4 I gave.